# Let $S$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ if $x\in gl_S (n,\mathbb C)$ then trace of $x$ is zero.

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

Let $S$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ if $x\in \mathfrak {gl}_S (n,\mathbb C)$ then trace of $x$ is zero.

Where $$\mathfrak {gl}_S (n,\mathbb C)=\{x\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C) \;|\; x^TS=-Sx\}$$

I tried to manupulate the equation $-S^{-1}x^TS=x$

I also know $tr(A)=tr(A^T)$

So $$tr(\underbrace{-S^{-1}x^TS}_{x})=tr(\underbrace{(-S^{-1}x^TS)^T}_{x^T})$$
$$=tr(-S^Tx(S^{-1})^T)$$

I tried to expand in terms of the entries of the matrix, but it is too messy and no hope.

Any hint solution would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint :** for every $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, one has $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$. Use that fact to simplify $tr(-S^{-1}x^T S)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ we have $$-tr(x)=tr(-x)=tr(S^{-1}(x^TS))=tr((x^TS)S^{-1})=tr(x^T)=tr(x)$$ and so extracting $-tr(x)=tr(x)$ we see that $tr(x)=0$.

Comment: In particular, the requirement that we work over complex numbers is superfluous; the proof works over any field of characteristic not equal to 2.

Answer (score 1):

$$-Tr(x)=Tr(-x)=Tr(S^{-1}x^TS)=Tr(x^T)=Tr(x)$$ Where the equality one before last is because trace is invariant under conjugation. $Tr(x)=-Tr(x)$ implies $Tr(x)=0$ as desired.